# Will codes built on higher Windows versions work on lower Windows versions?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have done alot of research but I didn't find the answer.
If I build an DLL using WINAPI with Windows 10, will it work on Windows 8, 7, etc?

I mean, I must include the Windows header file, so, does it conflicts with the lower Windows versions?

Or it is just about the functions you use?

(if I use a function that works on all Windows versions, will the DLL work on all Windows versions?)

Comment: It depends on what functions you call, and how you link your DLL. Maybe it works on lower versions, maybe not. Impossible to tell from here.

Comment: Have the compiler tell you, whether an API is available on your lowest target version, by setting the target platform (`WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT`). See [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx) and [Modifying WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx) for details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I mean, I must include the Windows header file, so, does it conflicts with the lower Windows versions?
>
> Or it is just about the functions you use?

It depends on functions you use. Usually new functions are marked with Ex. Microsoft leaves old code compatible, so all old functions are left. You just must learn if functions you use are too young and replace them with older ones if they are.

> (if I use a function that works on all Windows versions, will the DLL work on all Windows versions?)

If you use modern compiler it will link your dlls against modern c or cpp runtime libraries, so check out which libraries you use. If you use vs 2015, there even is an option allowing you to compile your code with Windows XP compatibility.

Comment: `Ex` isn't really much of an indication, as there were some `Ex` functions even as long ago as Windows 95 !

Comment: Ex stand for Extended (and it can refer to more advanced) . and how MulDiv can be ridiculous?

Comment: The `Ex` variants were introduced during the move from 16-bit Windows to 32-bit Windows (i.e. Windows 95). APIs that are kept around for compatibility reasons are explicitly marked as such (e.g. [GetProfileInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724360.aspx)). [MulDiv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383718.aspx) is neither deprecated, nor ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on Win32 functions you have used. See in MSDN from which Windows version the function exists - it is written at the end of description. Most Win32 functions are there from Windows95 times or even earlier. But recent VS versions (2003+) generate code compatible with Windows 2000 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

For the functions which do not exist in all Windows versions, you can load the particular DLL at runtime (LoadLibrary) and check for the presence of the particular function (GetProcAddress). If the function is not available, you'd need to either disable the functionality in the app or fallback to some compatible method.

Note that in general, you also might want to avoid to 64-bit and build the app as 32-bit (that will run on 64-bit as well, but a 64-bit app will never run on 32-bit Windows).